# How can I figure out this grammatical mistake?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I am not an english speaker and I need some help with a grammar mistake that has up to now costed -4 reputation to me (I am [this user](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/58376/jheidk51)  posted this question as guest by mistake and cannot actually find the "delete" button).

What actually happened is that I posted [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/50193/58376) in which I stated that the following two statements concerning an abortion that took place in 1973

''It never harmed anybody -- **it was a dead embryo** so the cells back then (were used), instead of being discarded, they were used for research.''

''  ... The kidney of the fetus was, with an unknown family history, was obtained in 1972
probably. The precise date is not known anymore. **The fetus, as far as I can remember was
completely normal. Nothing was wrong.** The reasons for the abortion were unknown to me. I probably knew
it at that time, but it got lost, all this information...''

where contradictory in the sense that an embryo (=fetus) may be "completely normal"  or "dead" but not both.

Then I realised that I had run into some terrible grammatical mistake since I received the following two comments:

"Why exactly do you think one of those two statements has to be false?"

"Completely normal from an aborted from an aborted fetus tends to mean that death was involved. Just because someone dies doesn't mean that their cells are not normal with nothing wrong with them."

I seems that somehow "completely normal" refers to the kidney and not to the fetus itself!

But how can that be?

Probably it is the context that matters so here are the full-texts from which I took these two statements:

The first one was taken from [France24](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20201020-how-fetal-cells-from-the-1970s-power-medical-innovation-today):

''It never harmed anybody -- **it was a dead embryo** so the cells back then (were used), instead of being discarded, they were used for research.''

and the second one from

[Alex van der Eb. "USA FDA CTR For Biologics Evaluation and Research Vaccines and Related Biological Products Advisory Committee Meeting" (PDF). Lines 14–22: USFDA. p. 81. Retrieved August 11, 2012.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170516050447/https://www.fda.gov/ohrms/dockets/ac/01/transcripts/3750t1_01.pdf)

''  ... The kidney of the fetus was, with an unknown family history, was obtained in 1972
probably. The precise date is not known anymore. **The fetus, as far as I can remember was
completely normal. Nothing was wrong.** The reasons for the abortion were unknown to me. I probably knew
it at that time, but it got lost, all this information...''

English grammar had never been my best but now it is of vital importance to understand.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: In the first sentence, both _(were used)_ and _they_ should be omitted.

Comment: Judging from the cross-posting on Skeptics.SE your concern isn't a grammatical or logical error, but that the vaccine was derived from cells from an embryo that was obtained from a "social" abortion, i.e. was killed. The apparent conflict could be explained by the mother having died, and the live embryo did not (*could* not) survive.

Comment: You say that you can't find the "delete" button on Skeptics.SE. Is it just underneath the question? There is a row of links something like "Share Cite Edit Rollback Close Delete Flag".

Comment: No I mean this post, it seems that as a guest -by mistake I posted here as a guest- I cannot delete this post.  If it is OK keeping this post as guest then no problem.

Comment: Actually my concern became grammatical since a moderator commented that "Completely normal from an aborted from an aborted fetus tends to mean that death was involved" which costed 4 votes against  [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/50193) post.

Comment: Before judging the facts I have to establish the facts. This is why I turnt to Sceptics.SE.  But I was based on writtings which according to the comments I had misunderstood. And the comments resulted in 4 negative votes, so how can I establish facts?   Who will ever bother for a question with 4 negative votes?

Comment: It is unclear what the question ***is***. Is it [Are or were aborted human fetal cells used in vaccine production?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48635/are-or-were-aborted-human-fetal-cells-used-in-vaccine-production)

Comment: What is your question here? There doesn't seem to anything to do with **grammar** at all.

Comment: You should have only one account across the StackExchange network. You have admitted to having multiple accounts.

Comment: Can you delete this post cause I cannot.

Comment: @DavidHammen That's not the case. Different accounts are fine as long as they are not used to get round the rules.

Comment: @grammarq You should be able to delete this question [if you register your account](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13683/).

Comment: The wording is confusing at best.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the English language.

Answer (score 1):

"an embryo (=fetus) may be "completely normal" or "dead" but not both."

The apparent contradiction is that the embryo was normal and yet it was dead.

Since children that are not normal, that have abnormalities, can be born and survive it is not a contradiction that one that is not alive could still be normal. You are referring to its anatomical condition not its current state of health.

It is not uncommon for people reporting second hand on the writings of physicians or other professionals to make their own interpretations of the findings to suit specific needs. Being able to point to the doctor's "own words" is a great tool for creating trouble where none existed. As such it is important to keep casual language or interpretations out of such professional writing.